# How can I change my Apple ID on a 5s?

Tags: apple-id

How can I change my Apple ID to a new one? iTunes was taking money out of my bank account in unauthorised transactions. In total over 13 months they took over £1,000. My bank refunded my money & stopped iTunes their end. But now my account won't work & I've 16 apps that need updating & I can't as Apple ID won't let me!

Comment: Please use tags relevant to the content of the question. For more information on tags, see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/tagging)

Comment: make a new ID, switch off 'find my iPhone', wipe & reset phone, set up with new ID. Buy all apps/music again.

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't think going so far as to wipe the phone is necessary. Simply change out the Apple ID, delete & re-download apps.

Comment: Assuming that Apple didn't just go mental & start charging for nothing; I'd prefer to believe my account had been compromised & want as little to do with it as possible.

Answer (score 1):

Your old Apple ID has presumably been disabled from purchasing apps since you initiated chargebacks with your bank for purchases. This in turn disables receiving updates as well.

You will need to [create a new Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/account). Then sign into the App Store on your device by tapping on App Store > Featured tab (if not already selected) > scroll to bottom > tap on *Apple ID: your-old-id@email.com* and select Sign Out. Go back to the same place to sign in with your new account. The first time you login you will need to add a payment method, even if you will only be getting free apps. I'd suggest not trying to add the payment method from the bank where you initiated the chargebacks, as that will probably simply serve to get the new account banned too.

The apps purchased with your old ID **cannot** be updated by your new ID, so you will need to delete them from your device, then re-purchase them (or in the case of free apps) re-download them. Either way, the app copies on your device right now will never be able to be updated, because they are permanently associated with your old ID.

Note that by deleting the existing copies of the apps, you *will probably* lose app data. However, if you delete one and immediately re-purchase/re-download the same app with your new ID, the data **may** carry over - no promises, but I've seen it work before. Do not restart your device between deleting and re-downloading, as doing so will *definitely* cause the data to be lost. If this works for you, remove and re-download one app at a time so there are no problems with iOS removing the data before the app can be re-installed.